# Using LINQ to group a dataset by a field and calculate the sum of another one based on a where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have this database design:

```
StartDate              Number  Branch
2/23/2014 3:00:00 AM   2       1
2/23/2014 3:00:00 AM   3       1
```

How can I use LINQ to group by `startdate` and sum the `number` and where `branch` = 1

The result must be able to loop to get the sum number.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward:

```
 var result = db.myTable.Where(x => x.Branch == 1)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
                        .Select(g => new 
                        {
                            StartDate = g.Key,
                            Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Number)
                        });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
 var result = 
     from x in db.myTable
     where x.Branch == 1
     group x by x.StartDate into g
     select new 
     {
         StartDate = g.Key
         Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Number)
     };
```